# Using protocol functions at unknown class

Tags: swift, casting

I'm using NSClassFromString to create class type. But I do not have the type as `ClassName.Type`, only as a string.
Although, I'm sure this class will be with `SourceProtocol`. And I want to call functions of this protocol. How can I do it?

I tried casting to this protocol. But protocol doesn't have inits. Therefore I can't use functions.

```
let use = NSClassFromString(source ?? "") as? SourceProtocol
```

Don't work
Here is the easist example

```
import Cocoa

protocol NeededMethods {
    func doSmt(str: String) -> String
}

struct FirstImplementatioon: NeededMethods {
    func doSmt(str: String) -> String {
        str.replacingOccurrences(of: "1", with: "0")
    }
}

let anyclass = NSClassFromString("FirstImplementation")
```

I wan't to call doSmt, without using FirstImplementatioon.Type

Comment: What do you mean by "Don't work"? What happens exactly? Any error messages?

Comment: Sweeper. I have protocol type, but I can't do anything with that, because I can't init class from protocol

Comment: I added example in question